# How to get all ip addresses on a docker network?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-network

I have containers running in a swarm stack of services (on different docker-machines each) connected together on an overlay docker network.

How would it be possible to get all used ip adresses on the network associated with their services or container name **from inside a container on this network**?

Thank you

Comment: hi Paul, any update on that?

Comment: Hi shay, sadly, no...

Answer (score 11):

1. Find the name OR ID of overlay network -

   `$ docker network ls | grep overlay`
2. Do a inspect -

   `docker inspect $NETWORK_NAME`

You will be able to find the container names & IPs allocated to them. You can do a fetch/grep the required values from the inspect output. You will find the output something as below -

```
    "IPAM": {
        "Driver": "default",
        "Options": null,
        "Config": [
            {
                "Subnet": "172.23.0.0/16",
                "Gateway": "172.23.0.1"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Internal": false,
    "Attachable": true,
    "Ingress": false,
    "ConfigFrom": {
        "Network": ""
    },
    "ConfigOnly": false,
    "Containers": {
        "183584efd63af145490a9afb61eac5db994391ae94467b32086f1ece84ec0114": {
            "Name": "emailparser_lr_1",
            "EndpointID": "0a9d0958caf0fa454eb7dbe1568105bfaf1813471d466e10030db3f025121dd7",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:17:00:04",
            "IPv4Address": "172.23.0.4/16",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "576cb03e753a987eb3f51a36d4113ffb60432937a2313873b8608c51006ae832": {
            "Name": "emailparser",
            "EndpointID": "833b5c940d547437c4c3e81493b8742b76a3b8644be86af92e5cdf90a7bb23bd",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:17:00:02",
            "IPv4Address": "172.23.0.2/16",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am looking for a way to do it from inside a container on the network... I update my post to make it clearer.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to execute this command from inside containers, first you have to mount docker.sock for each service (assuming that docker is installed in the container)

```
volumes:
  - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

then in each container you have to install `jq` and after that you can simply run `docker network inspect <network_name_here> | jq -r 'map(.Containers[].IPv4Address) []'` expected output something like:

```
172.21.0.2/16
172.21.0.5/16
172.21.0.4/16
172.21.0.3/16
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're using the default VIP endpoint, you can use DNS to resolve the IP's of a service. Here's an example of using dig to get VIP IP using  and then get the individual container IP's behind that VIP using tasks.

```
docker network create --driver overlay --attachable sweet

docker service create --name nginx --replicas=5 --network sweet nginx

docker container run --network sweet -it bretfisher/netshoot dig nginx
~~~
;; ANSWER SECTION:
nginx.          600 IN  A   10.0.0.3
~~~

docker container run --network sweet -it bretfisher/netshoot dig tasks.nginx
~~~
;; ANSWER SECTION:
tasks.nginx.        600 IN  A   10.0.0.5
tasks.nginx.        600 IN  A   10.0.0.8
tasks.nginx.        600 IN  A   10.0.0.7
tasks.nginx.        600 IN  A   10.0.0.6
tasks.nginx.        600 IN  A   10.0.0.4
~~~
```

Answer (score 4):

```
for n in `docker network ls | awk '!/NETWORK/ {print $1}'`; do docker network inspect $n; done
```

Comment: "Error: No such network: NETWORK". Without the column name: for n in `docker network ls | awk '{i = FRN + 2} i != 0 && FNR >= i {print $1}'`; do docker network inspect $n; done

Comment: Thanks Davlio, i've edited the answer but with a more explicit aproach to skip the column header: for n in `docker network ls | awk '!/NETWORK/ {print $1}'`; do docker network inspect $n; done

Answer (score 2):

First, find the name of the network which your swarm is using.

Then run `docker network inspect <NETWORK-NAME>`. This will give you a JSON output, in which you'll find an object with key "Containers". This object reveals all the containers in the network and their IP addresses respectively.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am looking for a way to do it from inside a container on the network... I updated my post to make it clearer.